# Ghostscript PDF to cropped TIFF

Tags: ghostscript, tiff

I need to convert a PDF to a cropped TIFF file. For now I have the following command, which crop nothing...

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -r600 -sCompression=lzw -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -sOutputFile=a2.tiff Orange_facture_721368628_20180301.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=200 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c quit
```

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've put the media size selection (DEVICE....POINTS and FIXEDMEDIA) **after** the input filename, you need to put them **before**. Unless you plan on processing multiple files, or have some specialist need to run PostScript after processing the input, the input filename must be the last thing on the command line.

Don't use `-c quit`, if you want Ghostscript to exit on completion use -dBATCH.